# why gcc keeps showing sign-conversion alerts when manipulating winapi's COORD's when I don't change data types?

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc, sign

I've got `-Wsign-conversion` option enabled and it is very helpful but sometimes it gives me these errors that I can't tell what are they about since I'm not combining different data types.

error is:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:5:12: warning: conversion to 'SHORT {aka short int}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   coord1.X += coord2.X;
            ^
test.cpp:6:12: warning: conversion to 'SHORT {aka short int}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   coord1.Y += coord2.Y;
            ^
```

code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
  COORD coord1 = {20, 20};
  COORD coord2 = {50,50};
  coord1.X += coord2.X;
  coord1.Y += coord2.Y;
  return 0;
}
```

And I know I can disable this option in file with `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` command but I'd like to ensure that here is pure GCC paranoia and not my fault.

Comment: You are technically combining different data types. `short + short` is `int`. When that `int` gets stored in a `short`, it could be out of range.

Comment: You should listen to the warnings and fix the problems. Disabling the warnings will hide genuine errors.

Comment: So how can I add two shorts to stay in same data type ?

Comment: Your code is ok. Gcc's warning is technically true but a bit painful. Please don't use the word "throw" as in your title, the compiler "prints" or "outputs" or ... a warning, "throw" is for runtime exceptions.

Comment: It is correct paranoia.  You can suppress it by telling the compiler that you know it can overflow: coord1.X = (short)(coord1.X + coord2.X);

Comment: @HansPassant why did you delete your answer? Looked reasonable to me, and better than one I could write. The only thing I would add is something about integer promotions.

Comment: Compiler messages are printed, not thrown. Exceptions are thrown, and not at compile time.